# Java server stopped working

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I have Java server, but I know really a little about Java. I develop to company in HTML, CSS, JS and JS libraries, but from today I am unable to start server again. Each file has error, for example, first one on the 5 line, where is that code

```
 import org.jongo.MongoCollection;
```

and it says error

```
`The import org.jongo cannot be resolved`
```

and I dont know what now. It worked yesterday and a lot of time before, so I have no need to know more about Java and so on. We are little company, everyone works from its home, another developer, who created this Java server have no time till afternoon, so I will try ask here, if something similiar happens to someone else.

Comment: `Maven` project? if so make maven update... Maybe removing app from server, then clean server and directory. Maybe if `Eclipse` IDE menu Project > clean ...

Comment: I find out, that update command `mvn clean install -U`, so I will try it.

Comment: Try providing infos such as: What server are you running? What environment/OS are you running on? And so forth.. - Also from what I understand your question to be this is less a 'programming' question and more a 'program' questions. Might be a better fit for superuser or another stackexchange platform.

Comment: Server is Java, thats all I know and OS Window 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply your application not getting required classes, reason is either your lib files not present in class path. check your class path. then clean the application.